# Heapsort order of magnitude slower than Bubblesort (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, bubble-sort, heapsort

I have implemented a `heap` data structure, and use it to sort. My understanding is that it is `O(nlogn)` complexity. However, when compared to `bubble sort`, it is order of magnitude slower -- and yeah, I tried running it for larger arrays. I checked some answers at SO (in particular [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613533/why-is-my-n-logn-heapsort-slower-than-my-n2-selection-sort) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467751/quicksort-vs-heapsort?rq=1)), but still lost. Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong here, please?

The results are:

```
HEAP SORT: 12415690ns
QUICK SORT: 71ns
BUBBLE SORT: 541659ns
```

Here are the codes:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

// #include "heap.cpp"
// #include "pqueue.cpp"
#include "sort.cpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template <class T>
void printVector (vector<T> A) {
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <class T>
vector<T> constructVector(int A[], std::size_t len, std::size_t num) {
    vector<T> res (A, A+len);
    for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < num-1; ++idx) {
        res.push_back(A[idx%len]);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2;

    int a[] = {4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7};
    std::size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    vector<int> HEAP = constructVector<int>(a, len, 32000); // (a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int));
    vector<int> QUICK = constructVector<int>(a, len, 32000); // (a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int));
    vector<int> BUBBLE = constructVector<int>(a, len, 32000);

    // cout << "Original Array: "; printVector(HEAP);
    cout << "HEAP SORT: ";
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    heapsort(HEAP);
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count() << "ns\n";
    // cout << "New Array: "; printVector(HEAP);

    // cout << "Original Array: "; printVector(QUICK);
    cout << "QUICK SORT: ";
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    quicksort(QUICK, 0, QUICK.size());
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count() << "ns\n";
    // cout << "New Array: "; printVector(HEAP);

    // cout << "Original Array: "; printVector(QUICK);
    cout << "BUBBLE SORT: ";
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    bublesort(BUBBLE);
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count() << "ns\n";
    // cout << "New Array: "; printVector(HEAP);

}
```

`sort.cpp`:

```
#ifndef __SORT_CPP_INCLUDED_
#define __SORT_CPP_INCLUDED_

#include <vector>
#include "heap.cpp"

template <class T>
void heapsort(std::vector<T> &A, bool increasing = true) {
    Heap<T> H(A, increasing);
    H.sort();
    A = H.get();
}

template <class T>
std::size_t partition(std::vector<T> &A, std::size_t p, std::size_t r) {
    T x = A[r-1];
    std::size_t i = p - 1;
    for (std::size_t j = p; j < r; ++j) {
        if (A[j] <= x) {
            ++i;
            A[i] ^= A[j];
            A[j] ^= A[i];
            A[i] ^= A[j];
        }
    }
    A[i+1] ^= A[r-1];
    A[r-1] ^= A[i+1];
    A[i+1] ^= A[r-1];

    return i + 1;
}

template <class T>
void quicksort(std::vector<T> &A, std::size_t p, std::size_t r) {
    if (p-1 < r) {
        std::size_t q = partition(A, p, r);
        quicksort(A, p, q);
        quicksort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

template <class T>
void bublesort(std::vector<T> &A) {
    bool swapped = false; 
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (std::size_t idx = 1; idx < A.size(); ++idx) {
            if (A[idx-1] > A[idx]) {
                // swap them
                A[idx] = A[idx-1];
                A[idx-1] = A[idx];
                A[idx] = A[idx-1];
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}
#endif
```

`heap.cpp`:

```
#ifndef __HEAP_CPP_INCLUDED__
#define __HEAP_CPP_INCLUDED__

#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Heap {
public:
    Heap(bool maxHeap = true) : heap_size(0), max_heap(maxHeap) {}
    Heap(const std::vector<T> &a, bool maxHeap = true) : A(a),  max_heap(maxHeap) {
        if (maxHeap) this->build_max_heap(); else this->build_min_heap(); }
    ~Heap() {}

protected:
    std::vector<T> A;
    std::size_t heap_size;
    bool max_heap;

public:
    std::size_t parent(std::size_t idx) { return (idx - 1) >> 1; }
    std::size_t left(std::size_t idx) { return (idx << 1) + 1; }
    std::size_t right (std::size_t idx) { return (idx + 1) << 1; }

public:
    std::vector<T> get() { return A; }
    std::size_t size() { return heap_size; }

    void sort();

    void build_max_heap();
    void build_min_heap();

    void max_heapify(std::size_t idx);
    void min_heapify(std::size_t idx);
};

template <class T>
void Heap<T>::sort() {
    if (this->heap_size <= 0) return; // Already sorted or empty
    if (this->heap_size != this->A.size()){ // Not sorted and not heapified
        max_heap ? build_max_heap() : build_min_heap();
    }
    for (std::size_t idx = this->A.size()-1; idx > 0; --idx) {
        A[0] ^= A[idx];
        A[idx] ^= A[0];
        A[0] ^= A[idx];
        --this->heap_size;
        max_heap ? max_heapify(0) : min_heapify(0);
    }
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::build_max_heap() {
    this->heap_size = this->A.size();
    for (std::size_t idx = (this->A.size() - 1) >> 1; idx > 0; --idx)
        this->max_heapify(idx);
    this->max_heapify(0);
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::build_min_heap() {
    this->heap_size = this->A.size();
    for (std::size_t idx = (this->A.size()-1) >> 1; idx > 0; --idx)
        this->min_heapify(idx);
    this->min_heapify(0);
}


template <class T>
void Heap<T>::max_heapify(std::size_t idx) {
    std::size_t l = this->left(idx);
    std::size_t r = this->right(idx);
    std::size_t largest;

    if (l < this->heap_size && A[l] > A[idx]) largest = l;
    else largest = idx;

    if (r < this->heap_size && A[r] > A[largest]) largest = r;

    if (largest != idx) {
        this->A[idx] ^= this->A[largest];
        this->A[largest] ^= this->A[idx];
        this->A[idx] ^= this->A[largest];
        this->max_heapify(largest);
    }
}

template <class T>
void Heap<T>::min_heapify(std::size_t idx) {
    std::size_t l = this->left(idx);
    std::size_t r = this->right(idx);
    std::size_t smallest;
    // std::cout << "DEBUG: " << idx << std::endl;
    if (l < this->heap_size && A[l] < A[idx]) smallest = l;
    else smallest = idx;

    if (r < this->heap_size && A[r] < A[smallest]) smallest = r;

    if (smallest != idx) {
        this->A[idx] ^= this->A[smallest];
        this->A[smallest] ^= this->A[idx];
        this->A[idx] ^= this->A[smallest];
        this->min_heapify(smallest);
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: I didnt look at your code, but just want to comment, that the big O notation ignores any constant terms, thus even if you tried with large arrays, a `O(nlogn)` algorithm might always be slower than an `O(n^2)` one for any practical array sizes, if just the constant term is huge enough.

Comment: I know that the constants get lost in the `O`, but I thought that `HEAP sort` had relatively small constants. Correct me if I am wrong tho.

Comment: I am not that sorting expert ;) and honestly the code is too long for me to investigate it in detail. I would suggest you to use a profiler to find out where the hotspots are.

Comment: Have you checked how the compiler optimised this code?  Recursive functions can be very expensive if they are going to remain as function calls because of the stack frame. I think the main mistake is to try and roll your own when there are so many good libraries around, unless it is to learn about sort algorithms.

Comment: Seems the heap sort example above is a bit off. Try rewriting the heap sort based on the psuedo code from the wiki article on [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Pseudocode) .  The wiki pseudo code is for increasing sort, but get that working first, then add the option for decreasing sort.

Comment: Off topic suggestion that will save you a lot of explaining later: When you are naming files that contain templates and intend to include them in other files, don't use the .cpp extension. Use .h or .hpp or .impl or whatever. .cpp will screw up how people will use them, how IDEs will use them, and generally lead to bad juju.

Comment: @rcgldr it is the same algo, it's the name of the routines and the direction of sifting that are changed (`siftDown` -> `max_heap ? max_heapify(0) : min_heapify(0);`)
@T33C I tried different compilation optimization, all of them give me similar results. I also tried playing with the order of execution, in case processor branching and caching is playing tricks - same story :(

Comment: @RafazZ - it's not quite the same, the example code above uses recursion, the wiki example is iterative, although that alone shouldn't cause  that much slow down.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your bubble sort doesn't swap, but only copy. This would make it somewhat faster. Not sure this alone explains being so fast, though.
2. Your `Heap<T>` makes a copy of the array. This can explain the slowness. I guess you forgot a `&`.
3. You should have noticed 71ns to sort 32k array is not real. Your quicksort never sorts anything. You can use `std::sort` for a reliable quicksort.
4. Too much is known at compile time and the numbers are far from random. Switch to arrays with random numbers in this kind of testing.